# Pardot Form Hidden Field to Pull in Value from another Form field

Tags: javascript, html, account, pardot, form

I have created a Pardot form (not a form handler). The form contains 2 fields called "Phone" and "Latest Phone number filled in". The "Latest Phone number filled in" field is a hidden field.

What I want to achieve is whatever is filled in on the "Phone" field then it will also pass the value to the hidden field of "Latest Phone number filled in". How is it possible to do this without using Form Handler?

I have added the following script to the form layout to try and achieve this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>



 <head>

 <base href="*********" >

 <meta charset="utf-8"/>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

 <meta name="description" content="%%description%%"/>

 <title>%%title%%</title>

 </head>

 <body>

 <script>

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    // Get the Phone field and the hidden field

    var phoneField = document.getElementById('phone');

    var hiddenField = 
   document.getElementById('Latest_Phone_Number_Filled_In__c');



    // Add an event listener to the Phone field

    phoneField.addEventListener('input', function() {

        // Copy the value from Phone field to the hidden field

        hiddenField.value = phoneField.value;

    });

  });

 </script>

  %%content%%

  </body>

  </html>
```

I have tested the form and it is not pulling in the phone number into the Latest Phone Number Filled in hidden field. Struggling to find out where I am going wrong here, any help much appreciated...